# Parse XML to get Child names of a node

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, python-2.7, xml-parsing

Im new to Python/XML. I want to parse an XML for getting data under a parent node.
My XML has a set of "Entity" nodes with different names. Under each "Entity", there is set of "Properties" as shown below. I need to get all Properties of a particular Entity. For instance, if its the Entity "Quit", I need to get the corresponding "Property" names separated with commas as a string; like, **{QuitId, QuitReason, Status, QuitTime}** using a Python script. I need only the "Name" attribute of Properties.

```
<Entity Name="Boot">
  <Property Name="BootId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="Status" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="BootTime" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset"/>
</Entity>
<Entity Name="Quit">
  <Property Name="QuitId" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="QuitReason" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="Status" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
  <Property Name="QuitTime" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset"/>
</Entity>
```

I could get the Property "Name"s of all Entities with below script. but, Im not sure how can I get only the Properties for a particular Entity; like "Quit"

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('D:\Code\XM_metadata.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for prop in root.iter('{http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm}Property'):
    print(prop.get('Name'))
```

Comment: Please post root tag (a requirement of XML) and attempted Python code.

Comment: You should read this tutorial, which describes the basics and how to extract data from a simple XML structure: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#tutorial

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I could get the names using the code added to the question. however, Im not sure how to get the "Property"s for a particular Entity

Answer (score 1):

I could get the names a s required. Thanks for your pointers.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('D:\Code\XM_metadata.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
properties = ''
for prop in root.findall(".//*[@Name='Quit']/{http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm}Property"):
    properties = properties + prop.get('Name') + ','
properties = properties[:-1]
print (properties)
```